# Dates difference in days as a fraction

Tags: python, date, python-2.7, datetime

I have two dates (datetime objects) which I want to subtract from each other. The result I am expecting is the number of days between the two. This is how I am doing it:

```
def get_days_between(datePast, dateFuture):
   difference = dateFuture - datePast
   return difference.days
```

The problem is, I need the number of days as a fraction. Example: If the past and future dates are only 12 hours apart, I am expecting the result to be 0.5 day.

How can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
from datetime import timedelta

def get_days_between(datePast, dateFuture):
   difference = dateFuture - datePast
   return difference.total_seconds() / timedelta(days=1).total_seconds()
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a fractional time difference, do as the implementation for `timedelta.total_seconds()` does:

> For interval units other than seconds, use the division form directly
> (e.g. td / timedelta(microseconds=1)).

(https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#module-datetime)

So in our case, we need to divide by one day:

```
from datetime import timedelta

def get_days_between(datePast, dateFuture):
   return (dateFuture - datePast) / timedelta(days=1)
```